# Overlaying many mutlple rectangular plots or area plots (facing limits on alpha aka transparency)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ideally, I could find a way to do this with area plots, but the example will be with rectangles. The issue is that alpha does not seem to be doing it's job. There might be a completely different approach to this. This example is imperfect also because the data is random, but essentially I get a giant blob because I cannot lower `alpha`.

An example I found from Hadley's `ggplot2` [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_rect.html):

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(10, 100, replace = TRUE),y = sample(10, 100, replace = TRUE))
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x, xmax = x + 1, ymin = y, ymax = y + 2)) + 
geom_rect(alpha=.01,fill="black") + theme_bw()
```

Here we see that alpha is sufficient and makes sense, it's sampled 100 times and alpha is .01. If all 100 occurred at the same spot, it should be black

[image: Working alpha]

Now let's bump it up to 10000 samples, which is what I have (morso in the area plot option which is what I really need to do).

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(10, 10000, replace = TRUE),y = sample(10, 10000, replace = TRUE))
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x, xmax = x + 1, ymin = y, ymax = y + 2)) + 
geom_rect(alpha=.002,fill="black") + theme_bw()
```

0.002 is the lowest I can get alpha before it shows nothing. I'll go ahead and share that plot:

[image: Minimum allowable alpha of 0.002]

The following:

```
geom_rect(alpha=.001,fill="black") + theme_bw()
```

Shows:
[image: A lower alpha showing nothing]

I know how to do this for scatter plots, but how do you "overlayer" many rectangles or area plots with `R`? I imagine this might involve calculating a Z value prior to sending it to `ggplot`, or doing some rigorous slicing and dicing of the area plot data, but I'm wondering if there is a solution that is already prepared and working.

Thanks for reading and for any help you can provide.

Comment: what graphics device are you using? I get a different image (looks fine with 0.002)

Comment: default on Windows for what it's worth. is alpha < 0.002 working for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is not 100% answer to your question. Just wanted to mention, that alpha can take up to 2<sup>8</sup> different values. In `ggplot2` this is scaled down to the range [0,1]. So every scaled alpha value less 0.51/256 = 0.00199 will give you 100% transparency.

Concerning your question, I just wanted to confirm that in my case the plot looks fine with `alpha = 0.002`. Relevant `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

...

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3
```